# Pig script/command to filter a file on multiple strings

Tags: java, regex, hadoop, pattern-matching, apache-pig

I am trying to write a Java program or Hadoop Pig script which will take a parameter of comma separated strings (e.g. `abc, def, xyz`) and filter a file for the records which contain one or more of these strings.

E.g.

Input File:

```
1    abctree
2    pqrwewe
3    rtrxyz45
4    abcxyz
5    234rt23
```

Input parameter is: `abc, def, xyz`

Expected output:

```
1    abctree
3    rtrxyz45
4    abcxyz
```

I am able to write the script which filters the file on 1 string, using `matches`, but don't know how to do that for multiple strings. Do I need to write a UDF for this?

***I have added the Java tag to this question, because as per my initial findings I will have to write a UDF which will be written in Java. So if anyone knows a way to write this in Java, please post your solutions.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out:

```
B = filter A by (n matches '.*string1.*' or n matches '.*string2.*' or n matches '.*string3.*');
```

This does the trick.

However, for my requirement, I will be accepting a "comma-separated" input from the command-line, e.g. `string1, string2, string3`. So the next task is to somehow separate individual strings and use them in the above expression. If anyone knows how to do it (especially without UDFs), please post.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about Pig, but in Java you could use something like this:

```
String[] words = input.split("[\\s,]+");

String line;
while((line = file.readLine()) != null){
    for(String word : words){
        if(line.contains(word)){
            System.out.print(line);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`contains` is enough to find the words. You could make a regex based on the `input` string and match on that. The expression would look like `foo|bar|baz`, but you need to escape meta characters so they will be literal during the match, which can be done with `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote`.